# Stata merge with duplicates in both master and using

Tags: merge, duplicates, stata

Say that I have two datasets:

```
clear all
set obs 4
gen a = _n<3
gen b = "b_"+string(_n)
gen n = _n
tempfile data1
save `data1'

clear all
set obs 4
gen a = _n<3
gen c = "c_"+string(_n)
tempfile data2
save `data2'
```

Both contain duplicates at the `a` level. But I would like to match them so that each observation in `data1` is matched to all observations in `data2` that have the same value of `a` (so that there are eight observations in the merged dataset). (merge 1:1, m:1, and 1:m clearly don't work, and merge m:m doesn't give me what I want.)

This approach works, but it is clunky. How can I do this in a simpler way?

```
use `data1', clear
bys a (n): keep if _n==1
merge 1:m a using `data2', nogen
sort b
tempfile m1
save `m1'

use `data1', clear
bys a (n): keep if _n==2
merge 1:m a using `data2', nogen
sort b
tempfile m2
save `m2'

use `m1', clear
append using `m2'
```

Comment: Have you looked at `joinby`?

Comment: @NickCox, I somehow did not know about `joinby`, but it is exactly what I want. Thank you!